# Google Spreadsheet iframe Does not show borders

Tags: html, iframe, google-sheets

On my website i got a google spreadsheet Iframe. It does work but it leaves out some cell boarders.

https://gyazo.com/188f70c2519366caf4fbc66361804b01  Shown here
https://gyazo.com/140f6ef1d78e2ebe5b4090dea6c02327 Spreadsheet i iframed 

 iframe code

```
<iframe width="1000" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SSWqRf2bRyGv7KM6Cb-wn8vvFtv9-D28d3aNMT3D4PY/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false" height="750"></iframe>
```

live spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SSWqRf2bRyGv7KM6Cb-wn8vvFtv9-D28d3aNMT3D4PY/edit#gid=9403979

screenshot of the whole spreadsheet 
https://gyazo.com/9a67fa760933b1b0fff69586bc6add58

Even more example of the cellboarders not working
https://gyazo.com/4dab75296fa2278c7d4142272b1b4c9d

I have no idea whats cousing it. Thanks in advance

Edit: See the problem your self here. Notice at Solo compare the spreadsheet with the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sfpsha84/1/